# Latex .tex file input highlighted, listed, code

Tags: formatting, code, programming, text-decorations, text-manipulation

I have the latex document:

```
\begin{document}

Document introduction.

\onecolumn
\section*{That's how the code looks like}

\begin{algorithm}

\input{z.tex}

\begin{algorithm}



\end{document}
```

And I wanted to make that z.tex (tex file is exported from program Mathematica) will looks like this: [image]

I think that "listing" won't work and I have to use "algorithm" but I don't know how. The tex in file after appropriate formatting looks like this:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I think that..." don't post your speculation, explain what you want to do and *what's wrong* (error messages, etc.) with the current solution instead.

Comment: Besides, you haven't shown what the `z.tex` file contains, and how the output is related to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to solve Your problem using `\usepackage{listings}`, soI have created file named `z.tex` and as a result everything working fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
The next code will be directly imported from a file

\lstinputlisting[language=tex]{z.tex}


\end{document}
```

Comment: After doing what You suggested, I get this: [link](https://file.io/OV6NXESAX2Jl)

Comment: @PawełChmolewski, sooooo is what You wanted or no? if no please clarify more

Comment: It is not what I want. The text should be nice formatted.

Comment: what do You mean "nice"?

Comment: "Nice" I mean appropriate formatting, I've updated post.